# Return a tuple from a moqed repository method

Tags: c#, moq

Is it possible to return a tuple from a moqed method?

Ex:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.MethodName(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns(a => new Tuple<int,int>(a.Item1, a.Item2));
```

Comment: You get an error when you run that code I presume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't compile. You will only get an int parameter in your Returns callback.

```
mock.Setup(item => item.MethodName(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns((int i) => new Tuple<int, int>(i, i));
```

Comment: So moq is not capable of returning a tuple?

Comment: @Mark It is, but you are trying to create one using another one. That won't work because you are only passing an int to your method, not another tuple. `new Tuple<int,int>(a.Item1, a.Item2)` won't work.

Comment: Instead of `new Tuple<int, int>(i, i)` one can use `Tuple.Create(i, i)` which is more concise. Generic paraneters to the `Create` method can be inferred at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply return the Tuple with values that you want (for example 1 and 5):

```
mock.Setup(m => m.MethodName(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new Tuple<int, int>(1, 5));
```

Or using lambda:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.MethodName(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(() => new Tuple<int, int>(1, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the method that is being "moq'd" returns a tuple, then I don't see why not... Keep in mind that sometimes you have to set the return value explicitly.

Try:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.MethodName(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<Tuple<int,int>>(a => new Tuple<int,int>(a.Item1, a.Item2));
```

If this doesn't work, then providing an error message might help